# OS laggy after echoing a string in file descriptors 0,1,2 (stdin, stdout, stderr)

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, stdout

I was trying to exploit capacity leaking to a C program (see below), by taking advantage of the non-existence of `fclose()` function to a file, that the program previously opened.

In short, the exploitation included the following command

```
sudo echo some_random_string >&3
```

The thing is I run the same command using `>&2`, `>&1` and `>&0`, as well (stdin, stdout, stderr).

My PC lags since then (for example mouse click doesn't work on browser from times to times)

Any idea about what is going on?

The C program is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void main() {
    int fd;
    char *v[2];

    fd = open("/etc/zzz", O_RDWR | O_APPEND);

    if ( fd == -1 ) {
        printf("Cannot open /etc/zzz\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("fd is %d\n", fd);

    setuid(getuid());

    v[0] = "\\bin\\sh"; 
    v[1] = 0;
    execve(v[0], v, 0);

}
```

Comment: No, none of these processes are still running. I rebooted the pc several times, in any case.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include that the problem persists after rebooting, that's important. It also means that the issue is likely something completely different. Was `&3` attached to a specific file when you ran this? By the way, `sudo echo foo >&3` is pointless. Only the `echo` will run with `sudo`, the `>&3` is run as a regular user (this is why `sudo echo foo > /newfile` will fail).

Comment: What about `top` -- does that show some process using lots of CPU?